# Why is there a margin around hr and img tags?

Tags: html, css, image, margin

I am trying to remove the whitespace around hr and img tags, I have not had any luck yet, Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DnLdH/).

Can someone show me how to do this?

Is it a good idea to use hrs instead of divs when creating a sepearation/surrounding? Should I use a div instead? Can someone tell me which one is the better option. Sorry for the short question.

SOME CODE :

```
<img class="banner margin_padding" src="http://goo.gl/ftvYk5">
<hr class="line margin_padding"/>
<hr class="line margin_padding"/>
<hr class="line margin_padding"/>

img.banner {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
hr.line {
    background-color: red;
    color: red;
    height: 20px;
}
.margin_padding {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

EDIT :

Borders have a default border size I forgot about and the image should be displayed block

Comment: It's unclear what you are talking about.  It almost sounds like you are referring to the margin on the body itself.  Or, are you talking about the border on the horizontal rule?  Be more specific, and include code here in your question.  Also, you might consider a CSS reset.  A simple one is `* { margin:0, padding:0 }`.  I don't use it myself... I prefer other resets, but it is not uncommon.

Comment: I said, `I am trying to remove whitespace around hr and img tags` Why would I be reffering to the body?

Comment: ... because I don't see any whitespace around your hr and img tags, unless you're referring to the whitepsace around the sides of all of them which is in the body.

Comment: add `body { background-color:blue; }` to the JSFiddle, and you will see it is most definately not the body, yet the element

Comment: You're going to have to take a screenshot and indicate exactly what you're referring to.  I'm telling you that the only whitespace I see is from the body.  Are you sure you're not looking at the border of the horizontal rule?

Comment: In your fiddle, view the source in dev tools and you will see an 8px margin on the parent body tag of the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `display:block` to your `img` tag and `border:0` to your `hr` tag.

```
.margin_padding {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: You sir, are a genious, I forgot that they have a border :P

Comment: @unableToCompile If you would have read my comment in the first place, you could have solved that problem 10 minutes ago.

Comment: @unableToCompile np, happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is the default margin of the `<body>` tag. The actual value depends on the browser.

A common practice to avoid most browser's different default values is explicitly setting `margin` and `padding` to `0`:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is referring to hr and img margins, not the default body margin

Comment: Ok. I don't see any other whitespace around the hr in the example, so maybe add a picture if you haven't solved it yet.

Comment: I think different browsers have different defaults